# Encryption in react and Decryption in django

Tags: reactjs, django, encryption, django-rest-framework, cryptojs

i'm building a authentication system using react and django, Now i have a problem i want to encrypt password in UI then send it to backend, but i don't know how to decrypt it back in django

I used crypto js in frontend.

```
const VITE_PASSWORD_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_PASSWORD_KEY;

export function EncryptString(data){
   var enc_string= CryptoAES.encrypt(data,VITE_PASSWORD_KEY ).toString();
   return enc_string;
 }
```

so now i encrypted like this and send it to server/backend

now how can i handle it in backend??

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is not really necessary as all of the web is working on HTTPS which is encrypted HTTP.

If you really want to try it yourself try this:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from base64 import b64decode

def decrypt_string(encrypted_string, key):
    key = key.encode('utf-8')
    encrypted_data = b64decode(encrypted_string)

    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CFB(), backend=default_backend())
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    decrypted_data = decryptor.update(encrypted_data) + decryptor.finalize()

    return decrypted_data.decode('utf-8')
```

You can play around with it and then add it to a middleware or view. My approach was to make a decorator which decrypts fields before it comes to a view:

```py
def decrypt_post_fields(decrypted_fields: List[str]) -> Callable:
    def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
            request = kwargs['request']
            for field in decrypted_fields:
                request.data[field] = decrypt_string(request.data[field])
            kwargs['request'] = request
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

And then use it in view

```py
class AnyView(...):
    ...
    @decrypt_post_fields(["password", "card_number"])
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # enter code here
```